# use recursive function to generate combination in Swift

Tags: swift

I have five arrays. I can use five for-loop to generate the result, but I need a recursive function so that I can generate the combinations from more arrays. How do I use a recursive function to generate the combinations? Each combination includes one element from the five arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need it to be recursive, but there are a few ways to do it, anyway. You can use higher-order functions to make an Array extension that does what you want:

```
extension Array {
  func everyOf<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == T>(ar: S...) -> [[T]] {
    return ar.reduce(self.map{[$0]}){
      perms, items in perms.flatMap {
        perm in Swift.map(items){ perm + [$0] }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This would work like:

```
[1, 2].everyOf([3, 4]) //[[1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4]]
```

or:

```
[1, 2].everyOf([3, 4], [5, 6])

//[
//  [1, 3, 5],
//  [1, 3, 6],
//  [1, 4, 5],
//  [1, 4, 6],
//  [2, 3, 5],
//  [2, 3, 6],
//  [2, 4, 5],
//  [2, 4, 6]
//]
```

But the different arrays don't have to be the same length:

```
[1, 2].everyOf([3], [5, 6]) // [[1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 6]]
```

And you can do it as a non-method as well:

```
func everyOf<T>(ar: [[T]]) -> [[T]] {
  return dropLast(ar).reduce(ar.last!.map{[$0]}){
    perms, items in perms.flatMap{
      perm in Swift.map(items){ perm + [$0] }
    }
  }
}

everyOf([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) // [[3, 1], [3, 2], [4, 1], [4, 2]]
```

If you're really into the 'aul recursion, though, here you go:

```
func everyOf<T>(seqs: [[T]]) -> [[T]] {
  return last(seqs).map {
    fSeq in everyOf(Array(dropLast(seqs))).flatMap {
      seq in fSeq.map{ seq + [$0] }
    }
  } ?? [[]]
}

everyOf([[1, 2], [3, 4]]) // [[3, 1], [3, 2], [4, 1], [4, 2]]
```

Comment: I am new to Swift. The Array extension did help me resolve the problem. Thank you.